# How do i change the container from mp4 to mov?

Tags: mp4

The IP Camera stores an mp4 type container. but my customer want me to change the type from *.mp4 to *.mov.
I trying to convert from mp4's container to *.mov's container a video in the
IP Camera. 
Can anyone tell me the exact way to change the container of mov from container of mp4 ?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -codec copy video.mov`

Comment: I want to change the header file on mov. Is it possible to change the header on the mov?

Comment: Change it from what to what?

Comment: my customer wants to change ftyp  ex) 00 00 00 1C ... 00 00 00 1F please help me

Comment: They you should do what your customer asked :)

Comment: How do I change that. I don't know how i change the header file on mp4 or mov because ffmpeg is library files.thanks

Comment: @차영민 just use a freeware **hex editor** (don't know if you're Windows or Mac)